# How 'up to date' is the local datastore in Parse?

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I have a list of PFObjects online with Parse.
They are all pinned to the local datastore in my app so they can be accessed while offline.
How can these PFObjects be as up to date as possible? Should I query for all the PFObjects in viewDidLoad of the app and pin them to the local datastore to make sure they are up to date or is there a more efficient way of doing this?